# How to set Let's Encrypt SSL in duckdns domain with Traefik

Tags: ssl, traefik, lets-encrypt

Now I set my IP in duckdns panel with domain 'domainname.duckdns.org'

And I want to set my Traefik web panel with Let's Encrypt SSL

And I installed Traefik with dockers stacks command

```
version: "3.3"

services:

  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.5"
    container_name: "traefik"
    command:
      #- "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.tlschallenge=true"
      #- "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.caserver=https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.email=MYEMAIL ADDRESS"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"
      - "--pilot.token=MY PILOT TOKEN"
    ports:
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "./letsencrypt:/letsencrypt"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
    labels:
      - "traefik.port=8080"
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`domainname.duckdns.org`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.tls.certresolver=myresolver"
```

And When I run with this command, still I can access web panel with 8080 port with domainname.duckdns.org (Not a subdomain) But when I access with https://domainname.duckdns.org, it shows and error 'Bad Gateway' But can connect with SSL. But in my web panel it seems that SSL certificate is already applied.
Is there any problem in my docker-compose file?

[image]